# Why is this code not printing the required value?

Tags: python, selenium

I have written this selenium program in python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
i=0
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://problogger.com/jobs/")

elems = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for postings in elems:
    href = postings.get_attribute('href')
    i = i + 1
    if i > 3:
        break
    else: 
      if '/job/' in href:
        print(href)
```

This program is not printing any of the job links if I use 'if' logic where 'i' is greater than 3. If I remove that logic, it's printing all the job links, although I only want the top 3 ones. Please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure all href contain "job"? Should the counter ```i``` should be inside the "job in href"?

Comment: Yes, your counter placement is wrong.  There are many, many `<a>` tags on that page.  You're giving up after the first three, long before you have seen any actual job postings.

Comment: Do you only want to check the first three anchor elements, or print the first three anchor elements that have an appropriate `href` attribute?

Comment: I only want the top 3 ahref elements which have 'job' in their URL. And there are many links on that page with an 'a' tag that don't contain the jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, not all the `a` elements are containing `job` in their `href` attributes.
To print the first 3 jobs links you can do this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://problogger.com/jobs/")

elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"/job/")]')
for posting in islice(elems, 3):
    href = posting.get_attribute("href")
    print(href)
```

To make this working don't forget to add appropriate imports.
This should work:

```py
from itertools import islice
```

Comment: At that point, it's much simpler to use something like `for postings in islice(elems, 3):` and skip `i` altogether. (Or `for postings in elems[:3]`, depending on what `find_elements_by_xpath` actually returns.)

Comment: What is islice?

Comment: @NamanBansal https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-itertools-islice/

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/pythons-iteration-tools-filter-islice-map-and-zip/

Comment: I tried your solution, but it is showing this error: NameError: name 'islice' is not defined

Comment: You probably missing import. Try this : from itertools import islice

Comment: Now the islice is working but it is showing 'href' is not defined

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry. The variable lost during editing the initial solution. Now it should work.

Comment: @Prophet it is still not printing the job URLs. It is printing "https://problogger.com/jobs/job" 3 times instead of any jobs.

Comment: You are right again. I was missing `/` inside the xpath. Now it should work.

Comment: Thanks! It works now! I have marked your answer as correct!

Comment: I see. You are welcome!